# html Text is cut at end of the page using PDFConverter

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert html page to PDF using PDFConverter in C# but i have a problem that some html Text and images are not being displayed correctly at the end of the page.it is cutting off the images between PDF page.

Iam using HtmlToPdfElement.AvoidImageBreak Property which is not working properly 
 Is there a way to prevent this while converting  html to PDF using PDFConverter in C#?

Thanks

Comment: provide your code we can't help you if we don't know how is your code, not mind readers my friend..

Comment: I am using HtmlToPdfElement.AvoidImageBreak Property which is not working properly